# session managment in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

i have to create a WPF desktop application that alow me to open a session every time when the couple password/username is correct,i have created my WPF interface and i have created my DATABASE to test every time if the couple password/username exist in my DATABASE,i have to open a new session when i click on the LOGIN button can anyone help me whith this please????

```
string connectionString = @"Server=SHAGGY-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=gestion;Trusted_Connection=True;";
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
cnn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM [session] WHERE login ='" + textBox1.Text + "'and password ='" + pass + "'", cnn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
  //open new session
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. Also, this code is open to an SQL injection attack. ( http://xkcd.com/327/ )

Answer (score 1):

WPF by default doesn't know the concept of a session. A session is usually a web related thing. You would need to create a "session object" which would be as simple as a new SessionObj(). The session table is just a log? If it contains data (such as serialized data on the web) then you wouldn't create a new session, but load it from the database?

Comment: can you explain it more i mean can you give me a simple example please

Comment: i'll explain more, i need something like what you have in your facebook, you write your username and your password , if it's OK it will open my new session witch is a new interface with 2 button "LOGOUT" and "lock"

Comment: You won't need a session for this in a windows app. It's a page or control or window containing the login form, other pages / controls / windows containing the application and a logout button. On successful login you go back to the login window and forget your data. As WPF applications always run, the session is implicit. WPF page concept: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/51860d02-2217-45c8-8f49-49771e7e002d/